# How to use custom ~/.xsession with gdm3 in Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic?

Tags: gnome, login, lightdm, gdm, xmonad

I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and can no longer choose my custom `~/.xsession` in the session menu in `gdm3` or `lightdm`. If I use `xdm` as the login manager my `~/.xsession` runs, but then I have other problems related to Gnome (my custom `~/.xsession` runs Gnome + XMonad).

How can I use my custom `~/.xsession` with `gdm3` or `lightdm`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can run `~/.xsession` with `gdm` by creating `/usr/share/xsessions/xsession.desktop` containing

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=XSession
Comment=This session uses the custom xsession file
Exec=/etc/X11/Xsession
Type=Application
DesktopNames=GNOME-Flashback;GNOME;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-flashback
```

and then selecting `XSession` from the sessions menu when I log in.

(I wasn't able to find a package containing such a file, but it's easy to create it yourself once you know what to do).